# Software with simple representation of all stars

Tags: star

Do you know any program similar to TheSky (astronomy software), which enables us to identify stars after clicking on them with a simple view (like in the figure)? Many thanks

[image]

Comment: Stellarium is a good one.

Comment: Is it possible a view like black stars on a white background?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to invert the color in the app, you'll have to find a way to invert your screen color or something, but that probably won't do the trick.

Comment: The old software xephem was like this, with simple graphics (as befits its nearly 30 year age) It's not actively developed any more.

Comment: What is the use case which makes a programme like TheSky or Stellarium not suitable or too complicated?

Comment: The website (rather than software) [in-the-sky.org](https://in-the-sky.org/skymap.php) has clickable and searchable objects in planetarium mode. screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgzMA.png You can adjust the magnitude threshold and zoom in to make more objects appear, and turn off the "show daylight", adjust the time, location, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Guide9 from projectpluto.com will do this.  You choose Chart mode (Display, Background, Chart mode).  Right clicking on a star or any other object will give you the information you want.

It runs on all versions of Windows.  It is not freeware, and is a bit dated in some aspects.